# Composition of compostion as a functor

Tags: programming-languages, type-theory, functional-programming, category-theory

"Composition of Composition" (i.e., `(.) . (.)`) in Haskell), has type `(a -> b) -> (c -> d -> a) -> c -> d -> b`. Apparently, this is an instance of `fmap`, i.e. a functor between two categories.

The question is: what is the domain and the codomain of this functor? How do we interpret this functor in terms of functional programming?

Comment: No, `fmap` can not have that type. `fmap . fmap` can, since `fmap = (.)` for the functor `X -> -` (for any `X`). In your case, the two functors are `c -> -` and `d -> -`. (For total obfuscation, `fmap . fmap` can be also be written as `fmap fmap fmap`)

Comment: Anyway, I think that this question is a bit too much Haskell-specific to be here. On StackOverflow we routinely handle Haskell questions asking for the underlying categorical ideas (and how faithfully, or not, they appear in Haskell).

Comment: @chi It is certainly not true that this question is specific to Haskell - we get categories in any pure subset of typed functional programming languages. Writing this in SML for instance does not magically change the categories involved.

Comment: @xuq01 Actually, it likely does change the categories involved (at least to the extent that it is meaningful to talk about categories).

Answer (score 1):

Consider

```
(.) :: (a -> b) -> (d -> a) -> d -> b
```

is the `fmap` for functor $F_d\colon \mathfrak{C} \rightarrow d/\mathfrak{C}$ from category of types $\mathfrak{C}$ to its [coslice category](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/under+category) $d/\mathfrak{C}$ on object $d$.  Similarly,

```
(.) :: ((d -> a) -> d -> b) -> (c -> d -> a) -> c -> d -> b
```

is considered the `fmap` for functor $G_c\colon d/\mathfrak{C} \rightarrow c/\big(d/\mathfrak{C}\big)$.

These two functor can be composed to get $G_c \circ F_d\colon \mathfrak{C} \rightarrow c/\big(d/\mathfrak{C}\big)$. Like all compositions of two functors, the `fmap` of the composed functor is the composition of `fmap` its two functor operands. In this case, the `fmap` of $G_c \circ F_d$ is

```
(.) . (.) :: (a -> b) -> (c -> d -> a) -> c -> d -> b
```

as in the opening question.

Comment: I realise the answer is only half right. The fact that category of types is closed needs to be used to make sense. Please correct it if you can.